# Laravel Database: Query Builder with SQL unnest()

Tags: laravel, psql, laravel-query-builder

In my PSQL table "m_testate" I have the task to build a query with **unnest**:

```
SELECT m.channel, m.qwertz as test, iteration.timestamp as iteration 
FROM m_testate as m, unnest(m.iteration_times) WITH ORDINALITY iteration(timestamp, id) 
WHERE m.project_id = 1 LIMIT 10
```

I tried it with fromSub:

```
        $result = Measurement::select(['channel', 'qwertz as test', DB::raw('iteration.timestamp as iteration')])
        ->fromSub(function ($query) {
            $query->select('unnest(iteration_times) WITH ORDINALITY iteration(timestamp, id)')
                ->from('measurement');
        }, 'iteration')
        ->where('project_id', $project_id)->get();
```

Comment: Have you got any success?

Comment: Yes, I didn't use fromSub, I used leftJoin 
  `->leftJoin(DB::raw('LATERAL unnest(iteration_times) WITH ORDINALITY iteration(timestamp, id)'), DB::raw('1'), '=', DB::raw('1'))`